# How do I create one of those draggable settings bars in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen those draggable settings bars for random things, but I can't seem to remember what they were called, and thus am having a hard time to search it up on google.

It was one of those bars where if you dragged to the right, the value increases and if you dragged it to the left, the value decreases.

What's the easiest way to create one of these in html/css/js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a range and is an input element:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="10">
```

To get the out put you could use JavaScript and `<output>`:

```
<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)">
<input type="range" id="a" value="50">
<output name="x" for="a b"></output>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/j9URj/)

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as soon as the time limit is up!

Comment: Are you like reading my mind? Holy crap. I was actually looking for a way to get an output O__O

Amazed~~

Comment: @Edasaur You said you wanted to drag it and have the value increase! Glad you needed it!;)